# parallel current datetime in tagstring

Tags: gnu-parallel

I'm using parallel to run multiple test suites and I want to prefix each output line from parallel with datetime to ease debuging.

This how I run parallel

```
parallel -j12 --linebuffer --colsep ';' --tagstring "$(date +%T-%Z) - {1}" -a commands bash -c {2}
```

But tagstring is evaluated when parallel is executed not with each output.
Is there way to print date with each output line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
parallel -j12 --linebuffer --colsep ';' --tagstring '{=1 $_=`date +%T-%Z`;chomp=} - {1}' -a commands bash -c {2}
```

You typically do not need `bash -c`.